# Problem with Return function in Code Conversion Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Write a function file_in_english(filename, character_limit) that takes a filename (as a str) and a character_limit (as an int). The filename is the name of the file to convert from Code Latin to English and the character limit is the maximum number of characters that can be converted (including newline characters).

The function should return a string that contains all the converted lines in the same order as the file

If the limit is exceeded (ie, a converted sentence would take the output over the limit) then the sentence that takes the character count over the limit shouldn't be added to the output. A line with "<>" should be added at the end of the output instead. The processing of lines should then stop.

The lines in the file will each be a sentence in Code Latin and your program should print out the English version of each sentence

Your function should keep adding sentences until it runs out of input from the file or the total number of characters printed (including spaces) exceeds the limit.

- You must include and call your english_sentence function. 
     You must NOT use the break statement anywhere in your code. 
     You MUST use while in your file_in_english function. You can only use one 
     return statement per function.

The input text file has the following data:

```
aughterleeoow anmeeoow essaymeeoow onmeeoow heteeoow eaningmeeoow ofmeeoow 
heteeoow omicceeoow ybeeoow enriheeoow ergsonbeeoow embermeeoow ofmeeoow  
heteeoow institutemeeoow rofessorpeeoow atmeeoow   
heteeoow ollegeceeoow edeeoow rancefeeoow authorisedmeeoow ranslationteeoow
ybeeoow loudesleyceeoow reretonbeeoow .leeoow esmeeoow .leeoow (paris),meeoow 
.a.meeoow (cantab)meeoow andmeeoow redfeeoow othwellreeoow .a.beeoow 
(london)meeoow ranslators'teeoow refacepeeoow histeeoow ork,weeoow ybeeoow 
rofessorpeeoow ergson,beeoow asheeoow eenbeeoow evisedreeoow inmeeoow 
etaildeeoow ybeeoow heteeoow authormeeoow imself,heeoow andmeeoow heteeoow 
resentpeeoow ranslationteeoow ismeeoow heteeoow onlymeeoow authorisedmeeoow 
one.meeoow orfeeoow histeeoow
```

Here's my program: ***(Expect Output different from my Output)***

```
def english_sentence(sentence):
"""Reverse Translation"""
consonants = 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ'
eng_sentence = [] 
for coded_word in sentence.split():
    if coded_word.endswith("eeoow") and (coded_word[-6] in consonants):
        english_word = coded_word[-6] + coded_word[:-6]
        if (coded_word[-6] == 'm') and (coded_word[0] not in consonants):
            english_word = '(' + english_word + ' or ' + coded_word[:-6] + ')'
    eng_sentence.append(english_word)
return " ".join(eng_sentence)

def file_in_english(filename, character_limit):
"""English File"""
space = ""
newone = open(filename)
nowline = newone.readline()  
characters = 0
while characters < character_limit and nowline != "":
    process = nowline[0:-1]
    space += english_sentence(process)+'\n'
    characters += len(nowline)
    nowline = newone.readline()
if characters > character_limit:
    space += "<<Output limit exceeded>>"

return space

Test Case:
ans = file_in_english('big_test.txt', 112)
print(ans)

> Obtained Output:

laughter
(man or an) (messay or essay) (mon or on) the (meaning or eaning) (mof or 
of) the comic by henri bergson
<<Output limit exceeded>>

Exected Output:
laughter
(man or an) (messay or essay) (mon or on) the (meaning or eaning) (mof or of)   the comic <<Output limit exceeded>>

Test Case 2: 

ans = file_in_english('big_test.txt', 8)
print(ans)

Obtained Output:
laughter
<<Output limit exceeded>>

EXPECTED Output:
<<Output limit exceeded>>
```

Please advise where I am going wrong.

Comment: Because Python is indentation-sensitive, it's *extremely* important that the code you show is formatted properly from the beginning. Furthermore, please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn [how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Done. Updated the question

Comment: The indentation is still not correct. The easiest way to do it is to paste your code into the question, then select it and press Ctrl-K (or Cmd-K on Mac). Also, since not all users here come from the same culture, it would be good to explain what "Code Latin" precisely is.

Comment: Re-edited as per your comment. Hope it is more clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're checking the length (stored in your `characters` variable) after you have already appended the current translated sentence to the output `space`. You should check if the length exceeds the limit before appending to the output:

```
def file_in_english(filename, character_limit):
    space = ""
    newone = open(filename)
    newline = english_sentence(newone.readline()) + '\n'
    while newline != '\n' and len(space) + len(newline) <= character_limit:
        space += newline
        newline = english_sentence(newone.readline()) + '\n'
    if len(space) + len(newline) > character_limit:
        space += "<<Output limit exceeded>>"
    return space
```

Comment: Dear blhsing, 
I tried using your code replacement, but now am not getting any output. Please advise

Comment: Also, since we are inside the While loop, the Character_Limit > Characters

Comment: Oops I did miss `characters += len(nowline)` in my replacement code. Please try again now.

Comment: No, you should still check `if characters > character_limit` because you want to `break` the loop when `characters` exceeds the limit.

Comment: Yeah, I was able to crack the missing statement. Thanks a lot for the clarification

Comment: I just updated the answer with the entire function in case you still have any incorrect indentation.

Comment: Wait wait...we are not supposed to use the break statement. Please advise

Comment: The code has to be rewritten in order not to use the `break` statement. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Understood it now clearly. Thanks.